# Pdf word text conversion

Tags: php, xml, flash

I want to implement on my own site a conversion script that convert pdf word ppt and so on into swf files!
Can you suggest any media library that can do that or any books for this topic?
Bassicaly I want to upload a file be converted and then use a flash based viewer to see the document Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [print2flash](http://print2flash.com/). I use this for one of my websites and it does a good job.